# How can I read lines from a csv file only if a variable equals to a certain value (20Gb+ csv file)

Tags: python, r, csv, stata

I have a csv file around 25Gb. And I have 64GB of ram. Though my ram can handle this large file, it takes too long. Besides, I do not need every line in the data. So I wonder

1. if it is possible to **read only the lines with the second column equals to a certain value**.
2. Besides, I wonder if it will really save time. Because I guess the software will still read in the whole file, and then remove the lines that do not satisfy the condition.

I prefer to use Stata. R and python are also good.

Comment: Both recommendations (so far) are strong: for brute-force reading performance, little compares with `data.table::fread`. For careful picking of specific data, I think `vroom::vroom` in general is offering a lot of potential, and I'm excited to see where it goes. ***However***, when the data starts getting this big (not "big data", mind you, though it meets similar wickets in my experience), I suggest you should really consider formalizing your data storage/access, such as SQL or something that deals well with partial-pulls, indexing, etc.

Comment: It doesn't have to be *big* DBMS or *big* SQL or even any of the distributed data systems (e.g., HADOOP) for you to benefit from the indexing and efficiencies baked into them. SQLite might have some good-enough power here (so you don't have to "invest" in a large-scale DBMS), as [another answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/332069/147602) posited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R's `data.table::fread` is great for this. Let's write a sample file:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(39439)

NN = 3e8
DT = data.table(
  ID1 = sample(LETTERS, NN, TRUE), 
  ID2 = sample(letters, NN, TRUE),
  V1 = rnorm(NN)
)
DT
#            ID1 ID2         V1
#         1:   O   h  0.1580064
#         2:   K   l -2.4281532
#         3:   F   z  1.7353759
#         4:   B   f -1.0911407
#         5:   M   w  0.7187998
#        ---                   
# 299999996:   D   u -0.8221716
# 299999997:   F   f -2.4881300
# 299999998:   W   t  0.0371132
# 299999999:   I   h -1.2020380
# 300000000:   L   s -2.2284455

# smaller than your data, but still large
format(object.size(DT), 'Gb')
# [1] "6.7 Gb"

# write to test file
fwrite(DT, tmp <- tempfile())

# size on disk about the same
file.info(tmp)$size/1024^3
# [1] 6.191435
```

Two options: (1) read and then filter in R:

```
rm(DT)
system.time({
  DT = fread(tmp)
  DT = DT[ID2 == 'a']
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  50.390  25.662  40.004
```

about 40 seconds

(2) use `awk` to filter, then read:

```
rm(DT)
system.time({
  DT = fread(cmd = paste('awk -F, \'$2 == "a"\'', tmp))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
# 350.170   3.775 354.638
```

The latter is much slower because the former operates in parallel. The advantage is that the first approach is not memory-efficient -- you first take up all the memory for the full file, before filtering to a smaller table. The `awk` approach only ever loads the filtered file into memory.

(2*) In this case, you can actually use `grep` as well, but note that this only applies because there is only one column that can contain `a` in this file:

```
rm(DT)
system.time({
  DT = fread(cmd = paste('grep -F ",a,"', tmp))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
# 164.587   2.500 167.165
```

---

PS beware the "sticker price" for `vroom` -- as mentioned, it only indexes your data, so comparing timings of *just reading* your data can be misleading -- you have to time how long it takes to *actually do things* with your data, as that triggers the data to load. Here's a comparison:

```
# to offset some re-reading optimizations in fread
file.copy(tmp, tmp <- tempfile())

rm(DT)
system.time({
  DT = fread(tmp)
  DT = DT[ID2 == 'a']
  DT[ , .(mean(V1)), by = .(ID1, ID2)]
})
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 61.930  31.740  52.958

library(dplyr)
rm(DT)
system.time({
  DT = vroom::vroom(tmp)
  DT = DT %>% filter(ID2 == 'a')
  DT %>% group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% summarize(mean(V1))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
# 122.605  56.562 129.957
```

(roughly the same comparison goes for skipping the third step)

Comment: Thanks for adding `vroom` to the benchmark - the documentation I've seen is light on specifics about how much is read and when, and this confirms my suspicions. Probably more beneficial the wider the data is (and the lower the percentage of columns you're using).

Comment: @GregorThomas yep -- I specifically made a benchmark using all the columns since I think that's fairest. Of course `fread` has `select=` if you're not planning to use some columns, and IINM those columns are skipped during reading (i.e., not read-then-dropped as happens with rows)

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between reading all the lines and actually loading the whole thing into a data structure that sits in memory.

In R, the `vroom` package will index the columns, then if you filter on a value in the second column it will only read the second column to find out when the condition is met, and then only read the relevant values from other columns. [Read about it here](https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/benchmarks.html).

In general, a command line tool like SED or AWK will be very good at pre-processing your data. They work by streaming the file one line at a time, so the whole file is never in memory. You could use that to create a smaller file with only the rows you're interested in, and then use your choice of programs to work with it normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same inclination as Gregor Thomas to reach for `awk`, but it actually seems slower than Stata's `import delimited`. Here's a simulation showing this:

```
#delimit;
version 16.1;
set more off;
clear all;
timer clear;

/* Fake CSV Data */
set seed 1234;

set obs 1000000;
gen id = _n;
gen keeper  = mod(id,10);

forvalues i=1/2000 {;
    gen x`i' = rnormal();
};

export delimited using "big_file.csv", replace;
!ls -lh "big_file.csv";

/* (1) import delimited */
timer on 1;
import delimited "big_file.csv", clear;
keep if keeper == 5;
timer off 1;

/* (2) awk + import Delimited */
timer on 2;
/* Grab all the data for obs where the second column equal to 5 */
!awk -F, '$2 ~ /5/' big_file.csv > smaller_file.csv;
import delimited "smaller_file.csv", clear;
timer off 2;

timer list;

!rm "big_file.csv" "smaller_file.csv";
```

This produced a 20G csv file, but `import` takes 622.3250 seconds and awk + `import` takes 1193.1510.